# Multiply OAuth clients

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am currently using only one OAuth Client ID in my app. The token will be used via a WebClient post request.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec.client-id=xxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec.client-secret=xxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec.scope=xx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ec.token-uri=https://xxx
```

Configuration:

```
@Autowired
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

@Bean
public WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    manager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(new DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(
            new RefreshTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(),
            new ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider()));
    
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(manager);
    oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("ec");
    
    return WebClient.builder()
            .filter(oauth2)
            //.filter(logRequest())
            .filter(handleResponseError())
            .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
}
```

Now I need to add another OAuth Client ID that will use the same token-uri and grant-type. Something like this…

```
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec1.client-id=xxx1
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec1.client-secret=xxx1
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ec1.scope=xxx1
```

How can I modify the configuration to support multiple OAuth clients so I can provide each WebClient the necessary Client ID ?

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

One solution will be to use as follows:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetails) throws Exception {
clientDetails.inMemory()
            .withClient("clinetOne")
            .secret("secretOne")
            .scopes("scope")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("GrantType")
        .and()
            .withClient("clientTwo")
            .secret("secretTwo")
            .scopes("scope")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("GrantType");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Shweta. What I did to solve this was to create another bean for the other WebClient. So each one has is own conf.